# Difference between size after resize in ImagemagicK

Tags: imagemagick

I have some problem about ImageMagicK Resize function.

I found that are some difference between Original image size and resized image size after I use resize().

the code like this,

```
m_b = m_image; //Original m_image's Image Size is 2000x1312
m_b.resize("256x167"); 

PixelPacket *Pixels = m_image.getPixels(0,0,m_image.columns(),m_image.rows());
PixelPacket *bPixels = m_b.getPixels(0,0,m_b.columns(),m_b.rows());
m_b.resize("2000x1312"); 

int w = m_image.columns(); //2000
int h = m_image.rows();//1312
int bw = m_b.columns();//2000
int bh = m_b.rows();//1310 ??????????????????????
```

What am I suppose to do for solving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to resize to some **exact** dimensions without worrying about distortion of the image's aspect ratio - which it seems like you do - add `!` after the new dimensions to tell ImageMagick that  *"I want it this size and exactly this size even if it makes people look fat or thin"*.

```
m_b = m_image; //Original m_image's Image Size is 2000x1312
m_b.resize("256x167!"); 

m_b.resize("2000x1312!");
```